# Pulling organization member information from various other documents

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a Sub to pull organization member information from various other documents after they've been imported. Is there a better way to do this?

This code appears to be successful, however it seems as though there is a better way to do it.

The goal is to reformat member names from LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME MIDDLE NAME to LASTNAMEFIRSTNAME and match it with other documents in which the member names are formatted differently - i.e LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME with no middle name.

When matched, the main roster will pull information from the matched roster.

How can I improve this?

Thanks in advance!

```
    Option Explicit: Option Base 1
Dim a, a2, b, cl As Variant, i, x, y As Integer, r, r2 As Range, LC, FC As String

Sub Test()

    y = sAlpha.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row: FC = sAlpha.Cells(1, 1).Address
    LC = sAlpha.Cells(y, 1).Address: Set r = sAlpha.Range(FC, LC): a = r

                    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a), 2)
On Error GoTo nxt
                    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
                        b = Split(a(i, 1), ", "): a(i, 1) = b(0)
                        b = Split(b(1), " "): a(i, 1) = a(i, 1) & b(0)
                        b = Replace(a(i, 1), " ", ""): a(i, 1) = b
                    Next i
nxt:
                        r.Value = a

    FC = sAlpha.Cells(1, 10).Address: LC = sAlpha.Cells(y, 10).Address: Set r2 = sAlpha.Range(FC, LC)

            i = 1
            For Each cl In r
                x = WorksheetFunction.Match(cl, r2, 0): cl = r2(x, 2): r(i, 2).Value = cl: i = i + 1
            Next cl


End Sub
```

Comment: This question might be better suited on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than here on SO.

Comment: Side note: if you don't declare variables explicitly they are considered as `Variant`; so by `Dim i, x, y As Integer` you get only `y` as an `Integer` type, by `Dim r, r2 As Range` only `r2` will be considered as `Range` type variable.

Comment: Thanks!  That may explain some other issues I've faced on my other projects.